# Color R plotly text annotations by gradient

Tags: r, annotations, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to make a `scatter plot` with `R` `plotly`, where the points are colored according to a gradient, and on top of that I'd like to text annotate several points, where I'd like the color of the text annotation to follow the same color gradient.

Here's a toy data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=-1*log10(runif(100,0,1)),id=paste0("id",1:100),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Here's the colored scatter plot:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

scatter.plot <- plot_ly(type='scatter',mode='markers',x=~df$x,y=~df$y,color=~df$y,colors=c("blue","red"),showlegend=FALSE) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title="Effect Size",zeroline=F),yaxis=list(title="Significance",zeroline=F))
```

which gives:
[image]

Then, I'm trying to add the text annotation.

First, I'm creating the annotation data:

```
ann.df <- df[sample(100,5,replace = F),]
```

Then I'm trying this to add the annotation text:

```
scatter.plot <- scatter.plot %>% layout(annotations = list(x=ann.df$x,y=ann.df$y,text=ann.df$id,xref="x",yref="y",showarrow=T,arrowhead=5,arrowcolor=ann.df$y,ax=20,ay=-40,colors=c("blue","red"),font=list(size=15,color=ann.df$y,colors=c("blue","red"))))
```

The text is added but not color coded:
[image]

Any idea how to get the text colored according `df$y` with the `c("blue","red")` gradient ?

Comment: Tricky, adding HTML to annotations does not help and the font color can only be provided for all annotations. Probably you'd need to hack it in with Javascript but I guess the result will be rather hard to see if the points in proximity have a similar color.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Could one use `colorRampPalette` in a clever way to explicitly create a column of colours in `df`? The next step would be to display the colourscales separately.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to achieve this using `plotly`. Maybe someone will have a better idea but in the meantime, it might be easier by simply using `ggplotly` to get what you want.

You could try this:

```
a <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = y, label1 = x, label2 = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_color_continuous(low = "blue", high = "red")

b <- a +  
  geom_text(data = ann.df, aes(x=x, y=y, label = id, color = y), hjust = 0, nudge_x = 0.05)

ggplotly(b, tooltip = c("label", "label1", "label2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the annotations still have hoverinfo which are black in colour.

Comment: @Ameya, In your own example you don't have hoverinfo for your annotation, so you can always remove them for my example.

Comment: I am not the question asker (not sure if that's what you meant by my example). Sorry, I was asking if there was a way to make the hovertext in the same colour as the text

Comment: @Ameya..sorry. I don't think it is possible. But, maybe someone else will have a solution to your question. Maybe with Javascript.